# Finding a Digit using Regex

Tags: regex, vbscript

Im tryig to find a Digit using Regex Vbscript,I used `\d{1}` or `\d`,Its finding any digits from a word or Date,I just dont want to extract from date or string,Its only a digit ,there is nothing around the digit or dot(`.`),How can I find it?

Example

```
12/12/2009 - No need to match

09 - no need to match

8. match

7 match
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming enthusiasts. The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed. Not to mention that shifting the goalposts after answers have been provided is not something that is looked upon favorably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex liek this:

```
(^|[\b\s])\d\b
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/jI9bU5/2)**

[image]

Comment: It matching with '1 , i wanted to avoid identifying "   '4  "

Answer (score 0):

If your specs are "match strings that consists of exactly one digit", use "^\d$" (begin of string - one digit - end of string) - as in

```
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = "^\d$"
>> For Each s In Split("12/12/2009 09 8 7 a7b")
>>     WScript.Echo s, CStr(r.Test(s))
>> Next
>>
12/12/2009 False
09 False
8 True
7 True
a7b False
```

If not, describe your specs un-equivocally.

**Update:**

As I did miss the dot in "8." and mixed "contain" and "consist", I throw in "^\D*\d\D*$" for "match strings that contain exactly one digit":

```
>> r.Pattern = "^\D*\d\D*$"
>> For Each s In Split("2/1/2009 09 8. 7 a7b")
>>     WScript.Echo s, CStr(r.Test(s))
>> Next
>>
2/1/2009 False
09 False
8. True
7 True
a7b True
```